# Using Condition (/;) for constructing big matrices

Tags: matrix, function-construction

I want to construct a big matrix where the input of the matrix element is based on the relation between the row indices and column indices.

Here's an example of what I tried but did not work:

```
f[n_] := n
g[m_] := m    
W[n_, m_] /; f[n] == g[m] := 1
W[n_, m_] /; f[n] != g[m]: = 2
Table[W[n, m], {n, 1, 4}, {m, 1, 4}]
```

I also tried the following (using the variable `n` on the LHS instead of `f[n]`), and it worked.

```
f[n_] := n
g[m_] := m       
W[n_, m_] /; n == g[m]: = 1
W[n_, m_] /; n != g[m] := 2
Table[W[n, m], {n, 1, 4}, {m, 1, 4}]
```

But that's not what I want since the relation between the indices is a bit complicated.

Is there any way to put a condition with a function on the LHS?

Comment: What are `f` and `g`? Moreover, would you please explain what exactly does not work?

Comment: By the way, you can simply use `Array[W, {4, 4}]` instead of `Table[W[n,m],{n,1,4},{m,1,4}]`.

Comment: For larger matrix sizes, the following should be more efficient `n=4; ConstantArray[1, {n, n}] + 
 Unitize[Outer[Subtract, f /@ Range[n], g /@ Range[n], 1]]`.

Comment: I still don't see what the problem is.

Comment: I'm guessing you had [lingering definitions](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/18562/45431). Try doing `Clear[f, g, n, m, W]` and then reevaluating your input.

Comment: @CarlWoll Thanks so much! I followed your link and added 'ClearAll["Global`*"]' in the beginning and now it works!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For larger matrix sizes, the following should be more efficient as `f` and `g` have to be evaluated less often.

```
n = 4; 
ConstantArray[1, {n, n}] + Unitize[Outer[Subtract, f /@ Range[n], g /@ Range[n], 1]]
```

Another possibility is this:

```
n = 4;
SparseArray[{n_, m_} /; f[n] == g[m] :> 1, {n, n}, 2];
```

This produces a `SparseArray` which can be converted to a conventional (dense) matrix by applying `Normal`.

For *really* huge matrix (`n` in the millions), some additional work pays off:

```
With[{nf = Nearest[f /@ Range[n] -> Automatic]},
 SparseArray[
  Join @@ MapThread[ Thread@*List, {nf[g /@ Range[n], {∞, 0}], Range[n]}] -> 1,
  {n, n},
  2
  ]
 ]
```

Comment: There is a typo: Absolutetiming -> AbsoluteTiming.

Comment: Thanks, @Lee. I removed it.

Comment: Thanks@HenrikSchumacher, yes for big matrices your ways are much more efficient!

Comment: You're welcome.